# Swift 4: Get RGB values of pixel in UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, colors, uicolor

I know there have been lots of posts for how to get the colour of a pixel in a `UIImage` given a `CGPoint` but they are all outdated as far as I can tell. Most of them contain `CGImageGetDataProvider` and `CGDataProviderCopyData` which in Swift 4 is an error:

> 'CGImageGetDataProvider' has been replaced by property 'CGImage.dataProvider'
>   'CGDataProviderCopyData' has been replaced by property 'CGDataProvider.data'

Xcode suggests these substitutes, but they do not exist so I have been having trouble trying to recreate a Swift 4 function to get the colour of a pixel in a `UIImage`.

Here is the typical Swift 3 function:

```
extension UIImage {

    subscript (x: Int, y: Int) -> UIColor? {

        if x < 0 || x > Int(size.width) || y < 0 || y > Int(size.height) {
            return nil
        }

        let provider = CGImageGetDataProvider(self.cgImage!)
        let providerData = CGDataProviderCopyData(provider!)
        let data = CFDataGetBytePtr(providerData)

        let numberOfComponents = 4
        let pixelData = ((Int(size.width) * y) + x) * numberOfComponents

        let r = CGFloat(data![pixelData]) / 255.0
        let g = CGFloat(data![pixelData + 1]) / 255.0
        let b = CGFloat(data![pixelData + 2]) / 255.0
        let a = CGFloat(data![pixelData + 3]) / 255.0

        return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
    }

}
```

Any suggestions or comments are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

---

**EDIT**

I tried @Mukesh 's solution but even though all the build errors are fixed, the program crashes. It says:

[image]

The image I give to the function is not `nil`, I have checked.

---

P.S. The image I am using for the function is a snapshot of the camera. I have a live camera and after every frame, this function (below) is called where I turn the current frame into a `UIImage`. This `UIImage` is what I want to find the pixel colour of:

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        let pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!
        let ciImg = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
        let cameraImage = UIImage(ciImage: ciImg)
        let col = cameraImage.getPixelColor(pos: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
   }
```

I used `CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)` to see if it crashed as an example, and it did. This point is also in the image because if it wasn't, it would have returned `nil` here:

```
if x < 0 || x > Int(size.width) || y < 0 || y > Int(size.height) {
            return nil
}
```

Is there a way to find out why it gets a `nil` value? Or maybe a different solution? Thank you :)

Comment: did you try this? `let provider = self.cgImage!.dataProvider
        let providerData = provider!.data`

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code I get after removing the errors:

```
extension UIImage {

    subscript (x: Int, y: Int) -> UIColor? {

        if x < 0 || x > Int(size.width) || y < 0 || y > Int(size.height) {
            return nil
        }

        let provider = self.cgImage!.dataProvider
        let providerData = provider!.data
        let data = CFDataGetBytePtr(providerData)

        let numberOfComponents = 4
        let pixelData = ((Int(size.width) * y) + x) * numberOfComponents

        let r = CGFloat(data![pixelData]) / 255.0
        let g = CGFloat(data![pixelData + 1]) / 255.0
        let b = CGFloat(data![pixelData + 2]) / 255.0
        let a = CGFloat(data![pixelData + 3]) / 255.0

        return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but even though the errors are gone the program crashes. Read the edit to my post, thanks!

Comment: Hi, could you please check out the error I get with your program in the edit. Maybe u can see if the error happens for u too, thank you

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you again, but just wondering, what coordinate system does the point of the UIImage work with? Is it UIKit - e.g. the point (0,0) is in the top left corner? Thanks!

Comment: UIImage and UIView use the top-left corner as the origin and Core Image and Core Graphics use the bottom-left.